# Why does web.config IsFile condition cause error 500

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I am working in on shared hosting service running IIS 10.0. On this server there is the following directory structure:

```
CommonRoot
|
+- MyRoot
   |
   +- WebSite1
   +- WebSite2
   \- Shared
```

I do not have any access on the directory CommonRoot (as expected). The first directory I have access on is the directory MyRoot.

Now I want to have a rewrite rule in my web.config for WebSite1 as follows:

```
<rule name="MyRule">
    <match url="^.*$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="CommonRoot\MyRoot\Shared\foo" matchType="IsFile" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/foo.html" />
</rule>
```

But this configuration causes an error 500. When I have detailed logging turned on, the generated page does not give any feedback on the actual error.

Now when I change the condition to the following:

```
<add input="CommonRoot\MyRoot\WebSite1\foo" matchType="IsFile" />
```

The condition suddenly works.

Since I do not have any access rights to the CommonRoot folder, I suspect that the condition check somehow checks if the web application has any access to any folder, counting backwards from the current application folder. Since I am on a shared hosting service, I also am not allowed (for obvious reasons) to set permissions on the CommonRoot folder. I surely won't be granted any rights if I would ask. Is this a known limitation?

The funny thing is, that when I use a Perl script on the same server, I can check if the file CommonRoot\MyRoot\Shared\foo exists and can even read the contents. So somehow IIS is doing the check if the file exists different than the Perl interpreter.

**UPDATE:**
Another strange this is, that when the file does not exist at all, the original condition does not cause an error. Only when the file actually exists, an error 500 is returned.

Comment: I suggest you use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information about 500.

Comment: @samwu To enable FRT it Deens that i need to have access to either the IIS manager or the applicationhost.config file. I am on a shared hosting service and don’t have access to these. In my local test environment it all works correctly, but not on the actual shared hosting server.

Comment: If can't use frt, it’s difficult to troubleshoot your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found out that it was all indeed a rights issue. The user that is assigned to the IIS server (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) needs to have access on the directory (and file) that is being checked in the rule, otherwise the check will fail.
If that user does not have the rights to read the directory, IIS will return a error 500 to the client when the file exists.

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. It is so appreciated if you can mark solution as answer.